# how to display different counts with different conditions?

Tags: mysql, sql, count, conditional-statements

I have to display two different counts with different conditions, first column shows the number of tasks `(COUNT(PROJECTWORKPLAN.TASKS))` and the other one is the number of delayed tasks which i get the logic but don't know how to type the statement.

the PROJECTWORKPLAN table has these columns which can be helpful for determining the delayed

```
tasks:
SDate - Start Date
ASDate - Actual Start Date
EDate - End Date
AEDate - Actual End Date
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the aggregate function `SUM` in combination with an `IF` expression to calculate sub counts.

```
SELECT
    COUNT(1) total,
    SUM(IF(AEDate>EDate,1,0)) delayed
FROM ...
```

Comment: I often use COUNT(if(<contd>, 1, null)). I prefer COUNT over SUM, may be that the standard I followed in years

Comment: hi i'm the one who asked the question. can this be answered using the WHERE clause?

Answer (score 2):

I guess delayed will be defined as if actual end date is greater than task end date then task is delayed so for this you can use `count()` for all tasks and `sum()` with case for delayed tasks

```
SELECT
COUNT(PROJECTWORKPLAN.TASKS) `all_tasks`,
SUM(CASE WHEN AEDate >EDate THEN 1 ELSE 0) `delayed_tasks`
FROM PROJECTWORKPLAN
GROUP BY PROJECTWORKPLAN.id
```

Answer (score 1):

This question is tagged "mysql".  Although I like the `case` statement version (because it uses ANSI standard syntax), MySQL has a great convenience:  it treats boolean values as integers.  So, "true" is `1` and "false" is `0`.  So you can do this with the simpler syntax of:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) total,
       SUM(AEDate > EDate) delayed
FROM ...
```